# Docker volume stops syncing

Tags: docker, synchronization, volume

I have a docker based system that comprises of three containers:

```
1. The official PHP container, modified with some additional pear libs 

2. mysql:5.7

3: alterrebe/postfix-relay (a postfix container)
```

The official php container has a volume that is linked to the host system's code repository which should in theory allow me to work on this application the same as I would if it were hosted "locally".

However, every time the system is brought up, I have to run

```
      docker-compose stop && docker-compose up -d
```

in order to see the changes that I just made to the system. It's possible that I don't understand Docker correctly and this is by design, but stopping and starting the container after every code change slows down development substantially. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong (if anything)? Thanks in advance.

My docker-compose.yml is below (with variables and what not hidden of course)

```
web:
  build: .
  links:
   - mysql
   - mailrelay
  environment:
   - HIDDEN_VAR=placeholder
   - ABC_ENV=development
  volumes:
  - ./html/:/var/www/html/
  ports:
  - "0.0.0.0:80:80"
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=abcdefg
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=thedatabase
  volumes:
   - .:/db/:ro
mailrelay:
  hostname: mailrelay
  image: alterrebe/postfix-relay
  ports:
    - "25:25"
  environment:
    - EXT_RELAY_HOST=relay.relay.com
    - EXT_RELAY_PORT=25
    - SMTP_LOGIN=CLASSIFIED
    - SMTP_PASSWORD=ABCDEFGHIK
    - ACCEPTED_NETWORKS=172.0.0.0/8
```

Comment: You definitely shouldn't have to restart Docker, I suspect it is either: a) the volume setup you have, and/or, b) how you are validating the changes. Can you please add more information about your 'web' service Dockerfile? Posting it is probably enough, but if it copies in bash scripts we may need to see those too! (I realise this is old ^_^)

Answer (score 1):

Eventually I just started running

```
docker stop {{ container name }} && docker start {{ container name }}
```

every time instead of docker-compose. using Docker directly instead of docker-compose is super fast ( < 1second as opposed to over a minute) so it stopped being a big deal

Comment: You can also use `docker-compose restart <container>`